# array.push() variable structured differently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using the script below. I am successfully adding the third part of the array using the php echo. I know this, because the document.write outputs it correctly. However, when I feed this array into my datepicker ... only the first two components of the array are used. Is the third part of the array being structured differently? Thanks for any help.

```
  <script>

    var enableDays = ["07-08-2013", "08-08-2013"];

    enableDays.push(" <?php echo mysql_result($result, 0, 'date'); ?> " );

    document.write(enableDays[2]);



    jQuery(function(){

    function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
        var sdate = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'dd-mm-yy', date)
        console.log(sdate)
        if($.inArray(sdate, enableDays) != -1) {
            return [true];
        }
        return [false];
    }

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays});
})


 </script>
```

Comment: still using `document.write`??? move on to `console.log` and **your third part is not a date**

Comment: Ok, thanks. Any ideas why the third part of the array is having no effect on the datepicker?

Comment: your third part is not looking like a date, considering it as string

Comment: Are the first two not strings? God im confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var enableDays = ["07-08-2013", "08-08-2013"];
 var dates = '<?php echo mysql_result($result, 0, "date"); ?>';
 // first check is coming or not if coming then push it into the given array

 enableDays.push(dates);
 document.write(enableDays[2]);
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that `mysql_result($result, 0, 'date')` returns date in format `dd-mm-yy`.

Assuming you get date from mysql in correct format, you are pushing `" dd-mm-yy "` into enableDays. This date cannot be found in array later because it has spaces around it. Try:

```
enableDays.push("<?php echo mysql_result($result, 0, 'date'); ?>");
```